# Why there is no option to import data to Azure database using ssms?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have created a SQL database on Azure portal.
I logged in to SSMS using required credentials, but some options to import/export data to database are missing, so I can't open SSMS Import/export wizard.


This issue doesn't occur when I using Amazon RDS databases.


Am I missing any database configuration?

[image: Screenshot of a Azure SQL database on SSMS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the best user experience with Azure SQL Database please use the latest SSMS version. Download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).

You can also try to add the Import/Export Wizard manually as explained on [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146715/sql-server-2012-import-export-wizard-not-showing-at-all) DBA StackExchange thread.

Answer (score 24):

You can see it by right clicking on the "Databases" not individual database.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqIt8.png)

Comment: Hm, so I can't import the data into an existing database, only to create a new one?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **SSMS v18** or above, you should right-click on the `Databases` and you can see that option there.

Answer (score 1):

It should be there: [image]
For creation of an Azure SQL Database use the following description:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal